# How to find an element in selenium whose locator value changes on mouse hover?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a drop down list where each element of the list is a search method, not a select tag. The list has a generic locator value. On select of specific search method, the locator value changes with respect to selected search method. I have to enter the search string, choose the search method and click search icon.

Now, I want to select the 3rd element, for example, search method of the list whose locator value changes on selecting it, and search the search string.

Comment: If possible, can you share your site url?

Comment: please share the 5-6 lines of html or page url is its a public site

Comment: @jainishkapadia : Sorry bro, its my office webpage. Cannot share the url. even if i share, u cannot access it.

Comment: @thebadguy: no its not a public URL

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

With this you can say things like "Find me all the elements that are inside a div with a given id" Or even "find me the third element inside a given div". Which is pretty much what you need.

See examples here: http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/xpath-locator-examples/